# Samba Share for Images used in a JasperReport

Tags: image, jasper-reports, samba

I was thinking, it would be possible to display an image from a samba share within a jasper report. But it isn't?
When I use the following it does not work:

```
<image scaleImage="RetainShape" onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement key="image-3" x="15" y="240" width="255" height="180" uuid="d9a3770a-777b-482b-a53a-dada5b71be1e">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{yzeichnung}.length() > 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{yzeichnung}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

whereas yzeichnung carries a path like "smb://mysambashare/directory/picture.jpg". The path itself is valid as I can browse the directory with Dolphin. So what is the key to get that going? Any thought's are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageExpression accepts also java `java.io.InputStream`. You have to choose a 3rd party library that can handle Samba.

For example, putting `jcif` jar from https://www.jcifs.org/src/ on the classpath,  you can use the following expression:

```
new SmbFileInputStream("smb://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + filePath
   + File.separator + fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I am familiar with the jcifs lib but I did not know I can use an InputStream there (at the ImageExpression).

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin includes a Samba client which is not available in Java applications.

If you want to read a file from a Samba share in a Java application, you'll need to mount the Samba share and then access it via the standard Java filesystem classes.

E.g. mount the Samba share at /mnt/mysambashare and then use /mnt/mysambashare/directory/picture.jpg in the report.